# How to get the unchecked checkbox values of JQGrid for each row when form submitted

Tags: c#-4.0, jqgrid, form-submit, jqgrid-asp.net, httppostedfile

I have a JQGrid with a checkbox column as shown below. Once I enter the required data in JqGrid, I do a form submit. From the http posted file I can read the values entered in each field for textboxes and dropdowns(all of these are required). But for Checkbox user can either check or uncheck. When form is submitted I only get the checked values of checkbox. I am retrieving the values as shown below. How to retrieve the values of unchecked checkboxes as well, when form is submitted

```
string[] checkValue = context.Request.Form.GetValues("clientView");

{ name: 'clientView', index: 'clientView', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False", defaultValue: false }, align: 'center' },
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it as per the [Demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithCheckboxes.htm). Added a Hidden field to save the checked and unchecked values of checkbox